# menu jquery toggle (page moves and menu acts weird)

Tags: jquery, css, menu

I don't know what I'm searching for, If there is a answer somewhere else let me know!

I have this page: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yFdzw

Now when I open and close the menu using the jquery toggle the page moves. Also sometimes when the menu opens it looks weird (screen)

https://www.dropbox.com/s/aks6qm1h40n2mrg/Screenshot%202014-06-10%2012.33.13.png

What could be the problem? or where should I look for a answer?

Comment: Try: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wvAhk ?

Comment: Ha thanks Aravona! That fixed it!

In the HTML on the a element there was a href that interfered.

thanks!

Comment: Not a problem. Glad you're sorted

Answer (score 1):

Please edit your jQuery and update with this script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $( "#toggle" ).click(function() {
    $( "#menu" ).toggle();
  });

});
```

and add "display:none" at **.bluebg** on your css, like this:

```
.bluebg{
    display:none;
}
```

hope that helps.